# Validate CSV file in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a csv file which contains two columns store_id and store_name.When the user uploads a csv file I need to validate the file i.e check if first column is Integer(store_id) and second column is String(store_name).Can you help how to read and retrieve the content and validate the file?

Thanks

Comment: [ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) may helps you to export. but in your case you need [angular-csv-import](http://bahaaldine.github.io/angular-csv-import/#/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

*my csv file*

```
    store_id,store_name
01,"First point"
02,"Second point"
03,"Third point"
```

```js
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('loadData', function($scope,$rootScope,$http){
   $scope.uploadData = function() {
    var uploaded=$scope.fileContent;
  $scope.processData(uploaded);
   };
    $scope.processData = function(allData) {
  var filteredData = allData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  var headers = filteredData[0].split(',');
  var final = [];

  for ( var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {

  if (!filteredData[i]=="") {

   var data = filteredData[i+1].split(',');

   if (isNaN(data[0])==false && isNaN(data[1])==true) {
    final.push(data);
    console.log("Valid CSV");
   }
   else{
    console.log("Not Valid CSV");
   }
  }
  }
  $scope.data = final;
 };
});
demo.directive('fileReader', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileReader:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).on('change', function(changeEvent) {
        var files = changeEvent.target.files;
        if (files.length) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
              var contents = e.target.result;
              scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.fileReader = contents;
              });
          };
          r.readAsText(files[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
 <div ng-controller='loadData'>
   <input type="file" file-reader="fileContent" />
   <button ng-click='uploadData($event)' >upload</button>
      <div>{{fileContent}}</div>
   <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td ng-repeat="y in x">{{ y }}</td>
  </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('csvUpload').onchange = function(){
        var file = this.files[0];
        var storeId = [],storeName = [],line,flag = 1;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
            var lines = this.result.split('\n');
            for(var iterator = 0; iterator < lines.length-1; iterator++){
                line = lines[iterator].split(',');
                storeId.push(line[0]);
                storeName.push(line[1]);
            }
            var result = !storeId.some(isNaN);
            for(var iterator = 0; iterator < storeName.length; iterator++) {
                console.log(typeof storeName[iterator]);
                if(typeof storeName[iterator] !== "string"){
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(result === false || flag === 0) {
                var alert = mdDialog.alert({
                    textContent: 'Please select a valid csv file',
                    ok: 'Close'
                });
                mdDialog.show( alert );
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

you may try this component
https://www.import-javascript-angular-xlsx-csv-validator.com/
it validates that and more